# How can I work on one java project and push my code to multiple git branches as I progress?

Tags: java, git, eclipse, github

I am currently doing a project for a bootcamp and I'm having some trouble. I need to demonstrate that I can use githhub. They want to see that I separate my crud functions onto different branches. So I created a repo using git bash, created a dev branch, with 4 branches coming off of that; create, read, update, delete. I checked out onto the create branch and pushed my create method coding to the create branch. I checked out to the read branch to push my read method code and the files disappeared from eclipse when I checked out to the read branch.

Do I need to push to the create branch and then pull to the read branch to continue working on my read methods?

Hope this makes sense to anyone reading

git checkout create
git add .
git commit -m
git push (gave me an error, prompted me to push upstream?)

git checkout read
// this is where my file disappeared from the package explorer in eclipse.
// my code was successfully pushed to github but I cant continue working on it when I checkout to the read branch
// my next step is to write my read functions, checkout to the read branch and push my code to the branch

Comment: When you run Git commands on the command line, you need to do a refresh in Eclipse. It would be easier and faster to do everything directly in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way they're wanting to see this done would be to

1. pull the code
2. git checkout -b [feature branch name]
3. Make your partial edits, commit and push
4. switch back to your base branch, git checkout [root branch]
5. Repeat at step 2 with you next set of edits.
6. Then issue pull requests to your root branch for your feature branches.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this worked for me. Managed to get it working and demonstrate what I need for the project